Problem with ClaimsPrincipal in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
I am trying to recover the user from the id that should be stored in a claim, to identify the user when creating an article.
I have the issue in the CreateAsync method.
I am using .NET 8.0.
public async Task<Article> CreateAsync(ArticleDto dto, ClaimsPrincipal userPrincipal)
{
    var userId = userPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

     if (userId == null)
     {
         throw new KeyNotFoundException("UserId not found");
     }

     var user = await _dataContext.Users.FindAsync(userId);

     if (user == null) 
     {
         throw new KeyNotFoundException("User not found");
     }

     var category = await _dataContext.Categories.FindAsync(dto.CategoryId);

     if (category == null)
     {
         throw new KeyNotFoundException("Category not found");
     }

     var article = new Article
     {
         Title = dto.Title,
         Content = dto.Content,
         Category = category,
         User = user
     };

     _dataContext.Add(article);
     await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

     return article;
}

The resulting userId is null.
Here it is my login method:
public async Task<LoginResponse> LoginAsync(LoginDto loginDto)
{
    var user = await dataContext.Users
        .Include(u => u.Roles)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync( u => u.Email == loginDto.Email);

    if (user == null || !VerifyPassword(loginDto.Password, user.Password))
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Credentials not valid" );
    }
    
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user!.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user!.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    };

    user.Roles.ForEach(r => claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r.Name)));

    var k = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    var signed = new SigningCredentials(k, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: issuer,
        audience: audience,
        claims: claims,
        expires: expiration,
        signingCredentials: signed
    );
     return new LoginResponse
    {
        Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
        Email = user.Email,
        TokenExpiration = expiration,
        UserId = user.Id
    };
}

I used Postman for some tests, if you are asking, yes I have included the token. I don't know what to do, I've been stuck with this problem for the past 2 hours.

Guys i figured out that i had to set the controller on [Authorize] and that's it, solved the problem. I know... i just forgot to do it before
